# How to remove the limits for sending emails in Salesforce

Tags: email, limits

My question is: How to remove the limits from a Salesforce org to send maximum number of emails in one day?

When I'm trying to send emails in Salesforce from Contacts objects an error msg is popping up saying that your organization has reached the limit of sending emails for the day, please try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can request a limit increase by following the directions in the [Help & Training documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334435&type=1). However, please be aware that the daily limits cannot usually be raised indefinitely, and you must have a valid business use case. If you need to constantly send large numbers of emails, consider using Marketing Cloud, Mailchimp, or another email service provider. Salesforce is not meant to be used as an unlimited email system. As the documentation states:

> The "Daily Single Email Message" limit is treated very similarly to the "Daily Mass Email" limit and is considered a "High Risk" feature by Salesforce Support. We understand that a limit increase may be necessary under certain conditions, but consider that Salesforce Support uses extreme scrutiny when reviewing these requests and we rarely approve indefinite increases.

Comment: If the Contacts are related to Users (i.e. have Client User Enabled so are linked to a Community User) then getting those Contacts' related Users and sending the email using the User IDs as the target IDs will avoid the limits being used - these limits only apply to "external email" and do not apply to Users.

Answer (score 0):

If your org was created before Spring 19, you can use the [REST Email Alert action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_email_alert.htm) and get higher [limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workflow_limits_email.htm&type=5): 1000 per license up to 2M/day.

In practice, this means having your org do a call out to itself which you can do through Apex.